# Show DebuggerDisplay in PropertyGrid C#

Tags: c#, properties, propertygrid, debuggerdisplay

I was wondering if it is possible to have the debugger display be the text for the class in the PropertyGrid?

I cant seem to find this answer anywhere.

Here is an example of what I have.

```
[DebuggerDisplay("FPS = {FPS}")]
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class DebugModule : Module
{
     public int FPS {get; set;}
}
```

This module is held in an Engine class so when I set the propertyGrid.SelectedObject = engineInstance, I would like to see in the property grid

> Engine
>
> > + DebugModuel    |   "FPS = 60"
> >
> > > FPS          |   60

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this, which displays the same text in the debugger and `PropertyGrid`:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{.}")]
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class DebugModule : Module
{
    public int FPS { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() { return "FPS = " + FPS; }
}
```

Or if you need to use `ToString` for something else:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{DebugDisplayText}")]
[TypeConverter(typeof(DebugModuleConverter))]
public class DebugModule : Module
{
    public int FPS { get; set; }

    private string DebugDisplayText { get { return "FPS = " + FPS; } }

    public class DebugModuleConverter : ExpandableObjectConverter {
        public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value,
                Type destinationType) {
            if(destinationType == typeof(string)) {
                return ((DebugModule) value).DebugDisplayText;
            }
            return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah that works. I just thought there would have been a little bit easier way. oh well.